# Can not store data in two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to store data in two tables, using two different queries.

one of them is working fine but other one is not saving anything . These two queries are part of full page script. The frist queries in both the cases are part of the scripts and working fine.
the 2nd queries are written by me to make another records of user clicks.

Table structure for  actcontest .. table name is actcontest not act_contest, this was copy/paste mistake here:[corrected]

```
userid  varchar(50)
type    varchar(50)
points  int(10)
date    date
```

Case 1:

The working query:

```
  $sql = $Db1->query('Insert into ptcwalllogs (userid, user_earned) 
 values ('.$credituser.','.$rate.')');
```

Problem with the query:

```
 $sqlact = $Db1->query('Insert into actcontest (userid, type, points, date)
 values ('$username','ptcwall',6,now())');
```

Case 2:
working query:

```
  $Db1->query("INSERT INTO `likesasapaddon` (user_id, page_id,date)
 VALUES('{$thismemberinfo[userid]}', '{$get['pageid']}',NOW())");
```

Problem with the query:

```
 $Db1->query("INSERT INTO `actcontest` (userid, type, points, date)
 VALUES ('$username','facebook',6,now())");
```

in both the cases I want to store values in same table.

Below is the script file for case 1: 
This is postback from one the providers.

```
<?php
$date1 = date('Y-m-d');
include("config.php");
include("includes/mysql.php");
$Db1 = new DB_sql;
$Db1->connect($DBHost, $DBDatabase, $DBUser, $DBPassword);

$your_pwd = ""; /* Postback Password */
$vip=getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

$sent_pw = $_GET['pwd'];
$credited = intval($_GET['c']);
$credituser = intval($_GET['usr']);
$rate = trim($_GET['r']);
$type = intval($_GET['t']);
$allowed_ip = array('72.52.253.202');//PTCWall's IPS.


if(in_array($vip, $allowed_ip) && $sent_pw == $your_pwd)
{
    if($credited == '1')
    {
        if($type == '1')
        {
            $run = $Db1->query('UPDATE user SET balance=balance+'.$rate.' WHERE userid = '.$credituser);
 // This line below is used to store clicks locally
        $sql = $Db1->query('Insert into ptcwalllogs (userid, user_earned)  values ('.$credituser.','.$rate.')');
$sqlact = $Db1->query("Insert into actcontest (userid, type, points, date)  
values ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($username)."','ptcwall',6,now())");
// $sqlact = $Db1->query('Insert into actcontest (userid, type, points, date) values ("lorry","ptcwall",6,now())');
            if($run)
            {
                exit('ok');
            } else{
                exit('issue');
            }


        }elseif($type == '2'){

            $run = $Db1->query('UPDATE user SET points=points+'.$rate.' WHERE userid = '.$credituser);
            if($run)
            {
                exit('ok');
            } else{
                exit('issue');
            }
        }

    }elseif($credited == '2')
    {
        if($type == '1')
        {
            $run = $Db1->query('UPDATE user SET balance=balance-'.$rate.' WHERE userid = '.$credituser);
            if($run)
            {
                exit('ok');
            } else{
                exit('issue');
            }
        }elseif($type == '2'){

            $run = $Db1->query('UPDATE user SET points=points-'.$rate.' WHERE userid = '.$credituser);
            if($run)
            {
                exit('ok');
            } else{
                exit('issue');
            }
        }
    }
}
else{
    die();
}
//FILE 03302014
?>
```

After the Var dump:

saved in separate file.

daata.php

```
<?php
$sqlact = $Db1->query("Insert into actcontest (userid, type, points, date)  
values ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($username)."','ptcwall',6,now())");
var_dump($sqlact);
echo " success asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdas " ;

?>
```

error:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in ./xxxx/daata.php on line 3
>   bool(true)

Kindly guide.

Comment: What do you mean, by "does not store"? Does it produce an error message?

Comment: query1 and query2 and written next to each other. first one saves data locally successfully but 2nd one does not do any thing. no errors. and nothing is stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in ./xxxx/daata.php on line 3 bool(true)

This warning means that you need to pass your DB connection to it, that is the second parameter it is expecting.

```
('".mysqli_real_escape_string($Db1, $username)."','ptcwall',6,now())")
```

Consult the documentation:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php**

---

```
$sqlact = $Db1->query("Insert into act_contest (userid, type, points, date)
 values ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($Db1, $username)."','ptcwall',6,now())");

$Db1->query("INSERT INTO `actcontest` (userid, type, points, date)
 VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($Db1, $username)."','facebook',6,now())");
```

---

Also, make sure that all your columns do exist in your table.

Add:

```
die('There was an error running the query [' . $Db1->error . ']');
```

This will signal an error, should there be any.

I.e.:

```
if($run)
{
    exit('ok');
} else{
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $Db1->error . ']');
}
```

- Follow that same method for all your queries.

---

It's also a good thing to add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

should `$username` or any other variables be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Here are working queries:

```
$sqlact = $Db1->query("Insert into act_contest (userid, type, points, date)
 values ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($username)."','ptcwall',6,now())");

$Db1->query("INSERT INTO `actcontest` (userid, type, points, date)
 VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($username)."','facebook',6,now())");
```

NB: **Always** use mysqli_real_escape_string (or it equivalent) for strings in SQL query. Or your application will be hacked soon with SQL injection.

Comment: does not work , either, this query also does not save anything

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure of your table name "actcontest" ? In the first case, you put an underscore in it and not in the second one. 
Are you also sure of this table schema : userid, type, points and date ? Maybe you made a little typo ?
If I were you, I'll first check all of that.

Comment: I did check all the things. and it saves the data queite well , if query is run spate. i.e. out side the script page

Comment: In the first query, you are wrapping your query with simple quotes and your are also using simple quotes in it without escaping them. This one couldn't work. And what is the name of the table you want to update ? Is it actcontest or act_contest ?

Comment: Ok, in the first one now, can you try to concatenate your values with "." like the working one above ?

Comment: I tried this as well
$sqlact = $Db1->query('Insert into actcontest (userid, type, points, date)
 values ('fakeusername','ptcwall',6,now())');

Comment: would u please tell . what can be the cause of not saving the data.. or no errors..  I tried this method and it works fine.. 
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO actcontest VALUES ('lorry','msurf',6,now())");

--- when its run outside the  script page.

Comment: And what's the value of `$sqlact` when you do this ?

Comment: And what is the value of `$sqlact` when you dump it just after executing the query : `var_dump($sqlact);` ?

Comment: updated the question, with errors after  with var dump

Comment: You need to send the connection with mysqli_real_escape_string. Try this : `mysqli_real_escape_string($Db1, $username);`. You can check this page for more infos : http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.real-escape-string.php